# PLAXIS API with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a beginner in programming. Recently, I used python API to remote control a software called PLAXIS (Geotechnical software). And there are certain code in PLAXIS can be accessed by adding g_i. in front of the program internal code. For example, there is an internal program code: 'Phase_8.ShouldCalculate = True'. So in Python, the format will be 'g_i.Phase_8.ShouldCalculate = True'. And, I have more than 10 phases. Now, I am literally writing every phases out in the code. May I know is there a more elegant way to do it? Please forgive me for my bad English.

Thank you very much!

I have try to define a function, but it does not work.

```
####What I am doing now####
if k >= 1:
    g_i.Phase_1.ShouldCalculate = True

    if k >= 2:
        g_i.Phase_2.ShouldCalculate = True

        if k >= 3:
            g_i.Phase_3.ShouldCalculate = True

            if k >= 4:
                g_i.Phase_4.ShouldCalculate = True

                if k >= 5:
                    g_i.Phase_5.ShouldCalculate = True

                    if k >= 6:
                        g_i.Phase_6.ShouldCalculate = True

                        if k >= 7:
                            g_i.Phase_7.ShouldCalculate = True

                            if k >= 8:
                                g_i.Phase_8.ShouldCalculate = True

                                if k >= 9:
                                    g_i.Phase_9.ShouldCalculate = True

                                    if k >= 10:
                                        g_i.Phase_10.ShouldCalculate \
                                        = True



####The function that I defined####
def setactive(k):
    g_i.Phase_(k).ShouldCalculate = True

for i in (1,k+1):
    setactive(i)
```

Comment: You should look into `getattr`, `Phase_(k)` won't work you need to build the string name.

Answer (score 0):

So, depending on value of k, it seems that you want `g_i.Phase_N.ShouldCalculate` to be true if `N <= k`.

To achieve that, I would put the phases into a list, like this:

```
phases = [g_i.Phase_1, g_i.Phase_2, g_i.Phase_3,
          g_i.Phase_4, g_i.Phase_5,]  # add more yourself
```

Now you can access `g_i.Phase_N` as `phases[N-1]` (e.g. `phases[3]` is `g_i.Phase_4`).

So, all you have to do is:

```
for i, phase in enumerate(phases):
    if i <= k-1:
        phase.ShouldCalculate = True

    # maybe you also want this?
    # else: 
    #     phase.ShouldCalculate = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate using this loop:

```
i=0

for ph in g_i.Phases:
   if k>=i:
     ph.ShowCalculate=True
   i=i+1
```

You can also access using the index: ph= g_i.Phases[i], being i an integer starting at 0 (initial phase)

You can also generate a list of phases in case you are creating your calculation phases programmatically:

```
ListPhases=[]
NewPhase=g_i.Phases[0]
ListPhases.add(NewPhase)

PreviousPhase=NewPhase
NewPhase=g_i.phase(PreviousPhase)

ListPhases.add(NewPhase)
```

Then, you have Access to ListPhases[i], being i the desired index. You can use zvone's method

I recommend you to take a good look at the Annex D of the Reference manual (this is for Plaxis 2D.), as it includes a lot of examples for beginners. There is some info on the Plaxis website, using VIP access

There is also some online (not free) training at the Plaxis Academy 
You can also check directly with Plaxis Support indicating your Plaxis VIP code, there are usually quite fast on answering.